# AutocompleteDropdownlist anchors to wrong textView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a dialogfragment with an autocomplete textview in an alertDialog. As the title does not layout according to my style I added a textView to show the title in my custom layout. Next thing I noticed that the dropdownlist from the autocomplete no longer anchors to the autocomplete but to the title textView instead. Image on the left. Removing the textView solves the placement. Image on the right.

[image] [image]

Setting the anchor with `android:dropDownAnchor` does not solve the issue.
Setting the title within the alertDialog keeps white space around the orangebar. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209964/styling-alertdialog-keeps-white-space-around-title-background). And removing the title is no option.
My layout file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_dialogtitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/overlayschedulepickerdialog_title"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="@style/ScheduleCompareDialogTitle"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_dialogtitle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup_main_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_teachers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Docenten" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_locations"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Lokalen" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup_main_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/radiogroup_main_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/radiogroup_main_left">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_students"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Leerlingen" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_groups"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Groepen" />

    </RadioGroup>


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check_own_properties"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Alleen eigen leerlingen/groepen"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radiogroup_main_right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/radiogroup_main_left" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup_branches"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/check_own_properties"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/radiogroup_main_left"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    >


</RadioGroup>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/acl_textinput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:hint="Zoeknaam"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/check_own_properties"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/check_own_properties"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:dropDownHeight="150dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

BTW, on my real device running Nougat the dropdownlist is anchored perfectly but not on the emulator running nougat or pie.

Comment: I think it might be because the system keyboard is not allowing any views to overlap on it. Not sure, though.

Comment: I restricted the length of the dropdownlist beacuse it disappeared behind the softkeyboard. So that is not the issue. As you can see in the second image the dropdownlist is not behind the keyboard